# VBA Copy and paste values from one worksheet to another based on matching ID's

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

So, I have this Worksheet1 which contains all the ID's and Worksheet2 which contains only few ID's. My code is able to match and paste values based on the matching ID's, but it is not looking at the entire value when matching up. For example in worksheet2 I have ID 132, so in worksheet1 it will paste the data in the row with number 132, but also paste it in row with ID 1, 3, 2, 13, 32, etc. How can I solve this so it only pastes the data in the right place

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is useless, it only does not let you seeing an eventual error. Then,  you should use more parameters for the `Find` function. Especially, `LookAt`. `Find` uses the former used parameters. If you tried (even manually 'Match entire cell content` not being checked) find for a partial match (`xlPart`) it will use it in VBA, too, **if you do not 'tell' to it what is to be searched**.

Comment: Could you share the preceding code where we could see the variable declarations so we could write a proper answer? Is `ws_Worksheet2` a variable or the code name of the worksheet? I mean, it's totally unacceptable, what's wrong with e.g. `wsLkp`? What about `1235`? Do you have data below that row or do you have formulas up to that row? Keeping track of the correct columns is certainly giving you a headache. You would be better off using the column strings instead of `.Offset`. Please add the additional code and information to your post.

Comment: There is no data after column 1235

Comment: There is no data after row 1235. The column titles match in both worksheets

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your Find the parameter LookAt with xlWhole. It should find only 132, not ID 1, 3, 2, 13, 32.

```
Set fnd = rng1.Find(What:=cll.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup: Non-Adjacent Return Columns

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LookupData()

    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Export"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_RETURN As String = "B,C,D,E,I,J"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Prepare"
    Const DST_LOOKUP As String = "B6"
    Const DST_RETURN As String = "L,S,Z,AA,AD,W"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Adjust if it's not!!!
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim slrg As Range, srrg As Range ' lookup, return
    With sws.Range(SRC_LOOKUP)
        Set slrg = sws.Range(.Cells, sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
        Set srrg = .Offset(-1).EntireRow
    End With
    Dim srCols() As String: srCols = Split(SRC_RETURN, ",")
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dlrg As Range, drrg As Range ' lookup, return
    With dws.Range(DST_LOOKUP)
        Set dlrg = dws.Range(.Cells, dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
        Set drrg = .Offset(-1).EntireRow
    End With
    Dim drCols() As String: drCols = Split(DST_RETURN, ",")
    
    ' Get the matching row indexes.
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(drCols)
    Dim srIndexes(): srIndexes = Application.Match(dlrg, slrg, 0)
    
    Dim srg As Range, drg As Range, sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Write the matches.
    For dr = 1 To UBound(srIndexes)
        If IsNumeric(srIndexes(dr, 1)) Then
            sr = srIndexes(dr, 1)
            Set srg = srrg.Offset(sr)
            Set drg = drrg.Offset(dr)
            For c = 0 To cUpper
                drg.Columns(drCols(c)).Value = srg.Columns(srCols(c)).Value
            Next c
        End If
    Next dr
    
    MsgBox "Data lookup finished.", vbInformation

End Sub
```